# How to select a old AMI out of 2 ami and if the old AMI is not there how to automatically select the new AMI using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two AMI's one is old and another one is new. What should be the solution to select the 1st Ami if its available if the 1st AMI is not there then my terraform file should automatically select the new AMI.

```
data "aws_ami" "rhel8_ami" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name = "tag:version"
    values = ["N"]
  }
  name_regex = "^RHEL8.*"
  owners           = [""]
}
```

Comment: The data source should throw an error if the AMI does not exist, there is no way around that. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @MarkoE no I am asking how can put a check or conditional statement so that I can use the 1st AMI by default and if its not there then my code should look for  latest AMI

Comment: You want to put the conditional statement **inside** of the data source?

Comment: @MarkoE yes and the conditional statement should 1st check for the old AMI and if the old AMI is not there then It should for look for the latest AMI thats is available

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible nor does it work that way.

Comment: @MarkoE so we have to use a single AMI and hard code the AMI name in the terraform script and go for dev stage and prod deploy then go for new AMI and change the AMI name again this should be the go ?